# Odd behaviour with sidekiq returned jid on a mailer when pushing into a serialised field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am getting some odd behaviour when trying to push a returned jid from a worker into a serialised field on a model. Best explained by this code:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :jids, Array

  def do_job
    test_jids = []

    jids << "s"
    test_jids << "s"
    Rails.logger.info("s has been pushed")
    Rails.logger.info(jids)
    Rails.logger.info(test_jids)

    jids << BarWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, self.id)
    test_jids << BarWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, self.id)
    Rails.logger.info("normal worker has been pushed")
    Rails.logger.info(jids)
    Rails.logger.info(test_jids)

    jids << FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self)
    test_jids << FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self)
    Rails.logger.info("mailer worker id pushed")
    Rails.logger.info(jids)
    Rails.logger.info(test_jids)

    jids
  end
end
```

Expected logging:

```
s has been pushed
["s"]
["s"]

normal worker has been pushed
["s", "6d25faf98b6448a43e1d3bb5"]
["s", "7144ceab11ece07ae352ffb9"]

mailer worker id pushed
["s", "6d25faf98b6448a43e1d3bb5", "54c4634bfc11ec1adad926da"]
["s", "7144ceab11ece07ae352ffb9", "3d0bb94e0411a04ab0339f68"]
```

Actual logging.

```
s has been pushed
["s"]
["s"]

normal worker has been pushed
["s", "243675806204134e6f05abaa"]
["s", "1444f558d7582df1000c6f4b"]

mailer worker id pushed
["s", "243675806204134e6f05abaa"]
["s", "1444f558d7582df1000c6f4b", "c0878213a8ea5f783c30e666"]
```

The job id for the mailer has not been pushed into the jids attribute on foo.

In the confusion I went a bit hacky and wrote this method on `Foo`

```
def do_job_with_assignment
  test_jids = []

  jids << "s"
  test_jids << "s"
  Rails.logger.info("s has been pushed")
  Rails.logger.info(jids)
  Rails.logger.info(test_jids)


  bar_worker_jid = BarWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, self.id)
  jids << bar_worker_jid

  test_bar_worker_jid = BarWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, self.id)
  test_jids << test_bar_worker_jid
  Rails.logger.info("normal worker has been pushed")
  Rails.logger.info(jids)
  Rails.logger.info(test_jids)

  foo_mailer_jid = FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self)
  jids << foo_mailer_jid

  test_foo_mailer_jid = FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self)
  test_jids << test_foo_mailer_jid
  Rails.logger.info("mailer worker id pushed")
  Rails.logger.info(jids)
  Rails.logger.info(test_jids)

  jids
end
```

Now this *does* produce the expected logging.

Apart from the obvious, what is the difference between the two?

**Edit:**

Nobody claimed the bounty, i want to take this further, but im not sure where the problem lies. Anyone suggest a good place to start?

**Edit: Classes**

```
> Foo.new.jids.class
=> Array

> BarWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, 1).class
=> String 

> FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self).class
=> String
```

**Edit:**

Demo app.
https://github.com/richkettle/sidekiq-oddities

Comment: You really shouldn't be sending an entire object (`self` in this case) into your  worker - this will cause serialization issues in Redis (though might be unrelated).  If you just send in self.id, or id - do you see the same results?

Comment: @Anthony you are correct. Though Im pretty sure its unrelated as the examples are the same.

Comment: I'd be suspecting something out of band right now like a hidden character in your non-working example.  In your `do_job_with_assignment` can you remove the `jids << foo_mailer_id` line and replace `foo_mailer_jid = ` with `jids << ` and **still** see the same problem of it not being added?

Comment: @smathy Just tried it, same result.

Comment: Freaky! There's no way my brain can make sense of that issue.

Comment: Can you check the types of `jids` and `jid`?

Comment: Ether you run this in very tight memory conditions or you get this logging not from this source (for example an older copy of your project), or this also may be as a result of hardware problems(very unlikely) -- `<<` should modify array whatever your `#delay_for.confirm_foo` returns. It's theoretically not possible ruby to behave like this. If you can please set up a small app with this issue and share it.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov this problem was initially from a larger app, i made a separate app to test it. I will share it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll clone and play with it later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because Rails caches attributes for all column types except serialized fields. With this in mind when you call the `<<` method on the getter for `jids` then Rails fetches the attribute for that field but when you then pass `self` into the mailer this again calls the getter when serializing in Sidekiq, and overwrites the attribute instance and so the returned value does not get added to the correct jids instance.

I'm not sure I fully understand why this is happening so some exact implementation details may be dodgy there!

This can be fixed/made to work with this version of Rails (4.1.5) by one of the following:

Cache the `jids` attribute:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :jids, Array
  cache_attributes :jids
```

Use the `jids` setter:

```
jids = self.jids << FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self)
```

Pass an `id` or a copy into the mailer:

```
jids << FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(id)
# or
jids << FooMailer.delay_for(10.minutes).confirm_foo(self.dup)
```

This is fixed in Rails 4.2 when this code is rewritten, a PR I could find is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15429

Comment: It seems you are right, `jids << ::YAML.dump(self)` doesn't add to the `jids` anything too. And workarounds do work. Trying to get what is under the hood with the method caching...

Comment: I believe it may be this bit here that constantly finds the value from the db field again and again.

I think I may have been incorrect about the method cache above and will remove it.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.5/activerecord%2Flib%2Factive_record%2Fattribute_methods%2Fread.rb#L111

Comment: Excellent catch. It's a good reminder that things which mutate a Rails field without using a setter will bypass ActiveModel's dirty tracking!

Comment: Yep @ChrisHeald thats exactly the explanation I was attempting to get to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my analysis...

`jids` is a `Foo` class member... and the way sidekiq works in the background (using [celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid) features to not allow race conditions and avoid deadlocks and a bunch of other features I have no idea about ).. make it do most of it's work in the background threads...

If my analysis is true... then the logging might look like following

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.do_job

# logs show the following
["s", "243675806204134e6f05abaa"]
["s", "1444f558d7582df1000c6f4b", "c0878213a8ea5f783c30e666"]

foo.jids
=>["s", "243675806204134e6f05abaa"]

foo.reload
foo.jids
=>["s", "243675806204134e6f05abaa", "I'm new here"]
```

while the `test_jids` is a local array that might be used before the end of the method... that's why it's returned immediately.. (and that is why your work around worked :D something to do with the way threads works)...

and please correct me if I'm wrong...
and if I'm not wrong... and you need more details... you have to dig deep on how is sidkiq and celluloid manages their threads

also have a look at the following

https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Gotchas

Comment: According to the source jid is returned after it have been simply put to redis, so it won't depend on background threads, and ruby won't continue execution before it returned from the function.

Comment: Hi @artmees, thanks for your efforts on this. I had suspected it has something to do with threading/a race condition. But exactly what, I have no idea. `reload` (i thought) just requeries the db for the record. Given that I'm not committing anything to the db wouldn't jids be blank?

Comment: It would be blank... I really don't know how to work with threads and process forks... But I'm pretty sure that is an issue with threading...  I faced a similar issue with wisper-celluloid gem but rspec was logging the failures of all threads.. Try adding a sleep for some time instead of reload... (And why are you extending ActiveRecord base when you are not committing anything to the db?)

Comment: @artmees i wanted the example to be as close as possible to the actual app where this is occuring. In that app the model _is_ committing to the database. I also tried sleep after seeing this answer, no difference.

Comment: And the reload in the app didn't work also ? (Just asking cause I'm out of ideas)

Comment: What do you mean by "reload in the app"?

Comment: No I meant reloading the too instance after do_job in the app (where the model is actually committing to the db)

Comment: `foo = Foo.new` `foo.jids => []` `foo.do_job` `foo.jids => ["s", "c7c8fbe32ecc2c359ff6d1de"]` `foo.save => true` `foo.jids => ["s", "c7c8fbe32ecc2c359ff6d1de"]` `foo.reload => true` `foo.jids => ["s", "c7c8fbe32ecc2c359ff6d1de"]`. Difficult to read but hopefully it helps.